# how big can a app engine datastore table be?

Tags: google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-datastore

I use the word table because in the console I can go visit a table and see all the entries it contains. So, how big can a datastore table be, in that sense? I haven't done app engine for a while so I don't recall. I think the proper term is entities. And so perhaps the question is how many instances of an entity can there be? In any case, I hope the question is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit. You can add as many entities of the same kind as you want. See a [list of all limits (quotas)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en) of App Engine.

The only limitation is money - you will start getting errors once you run out of your daily budget.

Comment: I linked to a page which lists all quotas.